# filter multi lines separated by a date time field

Tags: python, powershell

I have a logfile that are multi-lines separated by a date-time field like this:

```
2016-06-06 07:26:46,038: sometext...
sometext...
  sometext...
sometext...
2016-06-06 08:21:46,591:sometext1234...This is what I want...
sometext...abcd1234
2016-06-06 09:06:47,003: sometext...
2016-06-06 09:16:46,957: sometext...
  sometext...
 sometext...
```

The date-time always starts at the beginning of the line but the text can be on the same line or span multi-lines.  Is there a easy way to group and filter the date-time with the "sometext" in PowerShell (or python)?  Thanks in advance!

PS:
Just to be clear, I want to filter out from the above:

```
2016-06-06 08:21:46,591:sometext1234...This is what I want...
sometext...abcd1234
```

by giving the text "This is what I want"

Comment: There a plenty of ways to do it (in both python & powershell). Share what you've tried & we'll help.

Comment: For single line, yes, select-string, regx, ... But to group multi-lines, I don't know, unless I process the file as a whole.  I thought may be someone has some smart way to do that.

Comment: With what degree of certainty? Any regularity to the text at all? Dates always 2016? Text never has numbers?

Comment: PS's `-Split` can do it with RegEx... [`(?s)(?:[\r\n]|^)(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d{3}:.*?)(?=[\r\n]\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d{3}:|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/kO4nB6/1)

Comment: No, date is whatever the date-time, like nnnn-nn-nn nn:nn:nn format  The text portion will have numbers, but it should not have the same date-time format in it.  Basically, the date-time format is the delimiter for each grouping.  Using "2016" as the delimiter will not work as there might be GUID id in the text that contains 2016.  The text portion (sometext) is basically some error msg and stack trace of the error.  I am trying to filter out all the known errors, so I can see any new error, and the log file can be large (like couple hundreds MB).  Thanks.

Comment: @TheMadTechnican, That's a complex RegEx, let me digest a bit.  But it will have to apply to the whole file at once, I guess?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it took me a while, but I finally figured it out. And many thanks for everyone, who gave me ideas to test.  Even though, @TravisEz13's convertfrom-string was almost what I want, and I did use it in other applications, very useful, but I didn't use it for this case.  I ended up reading the file with get-content, but I didn't know before select-string has an option -context.  So I set the lines after very large (kinda cheating), and it worked.  Here is the code:

> gc "C:\abc.txt" | select-string '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}' -Context 0,100 | ?{$_ -match "whatever"}

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell [`ConvertFrom-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn807178.aspx) can take a template and convert data to structure output.  **You may have to adjust the template for your actual data.**

## Example

```
$log = @"
2016-06-06 07:26:46,038: sometext...
sometext...
  sometext...
sometext...
2016-06-06 08:21:46,591:sometext1234...This is what I want...
sometext...abcd1234
2016-06-06 09:06:47,003: sometext...
2016-06-06 09:16:46,957: sometext...
  sometext...
 sometext...
"@

$logTemplate = @"
{log*:{date:2016-06-06 07:26:46,038:}{message:sometext...}}
"@

$log | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $logTemplate
```

### Result

```
log                                                                              
---                                                                              
{@{date=2016-06-06 07:26:46,038:; message= sometext...}}                         
sometext...                                                                      
  sometext...                                                                    
sometext...                                                                      
{@{date=2016-06-06 08:21:46,591:; message=sometext1234...This is what I want...}}
sometext...abcd1234                                                              
{@{date=2016-06-06 09:06:47,003:; message= sometext...}}                         
{@{date=2016-06-06 09:16:46,957:; message= sometext...}}                         
  sometext...
```

Comment: Hi Travis, I don't see convertfrom-string in my system. I see convertfrom-stringdata.  Is there something I need to download or install?  This looks very promising and exactly what I need.  Thanks very much!

Comment: It is part of PowerShell 5.0 which comes with Windows 10 or you can install it [with WMF 5.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395)

Comment: Installed WMF5.0 and it works as Travis' example above, but It process line by line.  Is it possible to include the other lines as part of the message object?  Like "sometext...abcd1234" in "message=sometext1234...This is what I want..."?

Comment: @Spock can you update your question with your current code?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  I am just following your code example.  It works but I want the output to be something like this, if it make any sense:

Comment: {@{date=2016-06-06 07:26:46,038:; message= sometext...
sometext...
  sometext...
sometext...}}                                                                    
{@{date=2016-06-06 08:21:46,591:; message=sometext1234...This is what I want...
sometext...abcd1234 }}
...
`